# Is this construction with "as many.." correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say I am explaining a internet plan or a mobile carrier plan to my friend. I say

> You don't have to pay for the whole month. You just have to pay for **as many days** you use it on.

I would like to know if the construction of the expression in bold above is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost; you need another *as*:

> You don't have to pay for the whole month. You just have to pay for as many days **as** you use it on.

But aside from that, this is exactly right. The meaning fits perfectly.

Comment: just asking: What does _"use it on"_ (in this case) means?

Comment: @XPMai: The "it" is the Internet plan or mobile carrier plan. "On" goes with "days".